# python: how to return 2 columns/index in a list

Tags: python

I have a list that I generated using a for loop. it returns:

```
home1-0002_UUID    3457077784  2132011944  1307504896  62%
home1-0003_UUID    3457077784  2088064860  1351451980  61%
home1-0001_UUID    3457077784  2092270236  1347246604  61%
```

How can I return only the third and fifth columns?

EDIT
when I get an error it says 'Nonetype' object is not iterable

```
 for index, elem in enumerate(my_list):
    print (index,elem)
```

I also tried to get the index by using  list(enumerate(my_list)) but it doesn't work I get TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

this is how I populate the list:

```
def h1ost():
    p1 = subprocess.Popen("/opt/lustre-gem_s/default/bin/lfs df /lustre/home1 | sort -r -nk5",stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    use = p1.communicate()[0]
    for o in use.split('\n')[:6]:
        if "Available" not in o and "summary" not in o:
            print (o)
```

Comment: how is your list separated? can you add the actual output? is this a list or a dataframe?

Comment: `[[col[2], col[4]] for col in the_list]` ?

Comment: is it an array of arrays?

Comment: I updated the question with the error. I am using a subprocess to use a find command that returns the list from our filesystem. I hope that makes sense

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your problem. i.e. show the code that is not working.

Comment: Please share a code which gives you "NoneType object is not iterable" error.

Comment: @mustang_39211 The error is indicating that your `my_list` is `None`. At least that is what it seems like based on what you are showing. You will have to do some more troubleshooting to help narrow down where in the rest of your code the problem is *actually* happening and then share that with the appropriate explanation.

Comment: my roadblock is that i have to use a subprocesses to generate these lists using a lustre filesystem command, lfs find.

Comment: This is what I use to generate the list i updated the post.

Comment: @mustang_39211 Now did you try printing along the way to see at what point you are getting a `None` in your list? If you investigate further to see at what point in your manipulation you are not getting the data you expect, that is the root of your problem.

Comment: Try --- p1 = subprocess.Popen("/opt/lustre-gem_s/default/bin/lfs df /lustre/home1 | sort -r -nk5",shell=True)

Comment: without the stdout I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I cannot post a comment I will do my best to give you a solution to the question.

```
def empty_string_filter(value):
    return value != ''

def h1ost():
    p1 = subprocess.Popen("/opt/lustre-gem_s/default/bin/lfs df /lustre/home1 | sort -r -nk5",stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    use = p1.communicate()[0]
    new_file_content_list = [] 
    # Separate by line break and filter any empty string
    filtered_use_list = filter(empty_string_filter, use.split(os.linesep)[:6])
    for line in filtered_use_list :
        # Split the line and filter the empty strings in order to keep only
        # columns with information
        split_line = filter(empty_string_filter, line.split(' '))
        # Beware! This will only work if each line has 5 or more data columns
        # I guess the correct option is to check if it has at least 5 columns
        # and if it hasn't do not store the information or raise an exception. 
        # It's up to you.

        new_file_content_list.append('{0} {1}'.format(split_line[2] , split_line[4]))

    return os.linesep.join(new_file_content_list)
```

So the idea is split every single line by white spaces and filter any empty string left in order to get the 3rd and 5th column (index 2 and 4 respectively)

Comment: thank you for the response. This works very well. The result is h1ost()
    (['62%', '61%', '61%', '60%', '59%'], ['/lustre/home1[OST:2]', '/lustre/home1[OST:3]', '/lustre/home1[OST:1]', '/lustre/home1[OST:0]', '/lustre/home1[OST:4]'])
Can it be formatted back to the orignal state or is that acheived by writing that to a file?

Comment: I have modified the answer in order to retrieve a single string ready to be written  out to a file. Normally the joining would be done in an external function  in order to allow data management

Comment: this works great! The \n in the return line up perfectly when I print the return.